# why google can know my location when I use proxy connect network?

Tags: networking, proxy

I in china use proxy connect network by means of shadowscoks. However, google can auto switch language to chinese when I browse youtube.I think google only know my vps ip, and my vps in Los Angeles.so I am  very confused about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web browsers send lots of information in their HTTP request headers (see [What HTTP Headers is my browser sending?](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending)).  Most notably, browsers usually send an `Accept-Language` header, which tells web servers which language(s) are acceptable for content to be sent in.  Some web servers offer content in multiple languages, so they would pay attention to that preference.  A web server may send back a `Content-Length` response header to indicate the particular language(s) chosen.

So, in your case, YouTube could simply be picking up on your browser's preference for Chinese and not look at your IP at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you go on any site, the webpage collects information about you and your preferences. These things are called Cookies & Cache. If you go on any Google site and your language is Chinese, Google will remember that in the form of a cookie or save it in a thing called a cache, and whenever you go on any google site it will know and switch it to that language. It's for your convenience and probably has nothing to do with your IP.